# Sandboxing Issues

Tags: macos, sandbox

So I have to implement sandboxing in order to keep my Mac app in the Mac app store. When I enable sandboxing, my application works for the most part. I use the "top" command to get my CPU info and RAM info for the entire user's system. With sandboxing, I no longer have access to these features. This is the runtime error received:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/top: Operation not permitted
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/top: Operation not permitted
2012-05-29 20:40:57.911 QuickToggles[53714:403] *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
2012-05-29 20:40:57.928 QuickToggles[53714:403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff986bcf56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff97f98d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98666370 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 208
    3   QuickToggles                        0x0000000100001961 -[StatusBarAppAppDelegate updateInfo:] + 177
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff94666f40 __NSFireTimer + 102
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98671934 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98671486 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 534
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98651e11 __CFRunLoopRun + 1617
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98651486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    9   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9806b4d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff980726d3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 181
    11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9807260e BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff90441e31 _DPSNextEvent + 659
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff90441735 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff9043e071 -[NSApplication run] + 470
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff906ba244 NSApplicationMain + 867
    16  QuickToggles                        0x0000000100001882 main + 34
    17  QuickToggles                        0x0000000100001854 start + 52
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Comment: Does your platform provide the `getrusage()` function? Does it provide the details you need? (Parsing `top` feels like a gross way to discover this information in the first place, but that's just me..)

Comment: Of course this doesn't work; top tries to get information about every process on the system, which obviously isn't allowed inside your sandbox. @sarnold: Yes, there's getrusage, including RUSAGE_CHILDREN (important if his application is spawning a bunch of a child processes, which seems likely).

Comment: My application does not get resource usage of the application itself but gets it for the entire computer. Parsing top has been the easiest way I see to get the statistics in an easy clean fashion.

Comment: Your initial description said "get my CPU info and RAM info for my application", which is doable. Now you're asking to get that info for all processes, which is probably not doable—and, if you find a way, it's probably a bug that Apple will close later. If you just want summary information, that may—depending on what info you want—be doable in a different way, but you'll really need to tell us exactly what you want before anyone can tell you how to get it.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that there are ways to get around the sandbox that are, when done under direct user control, allowable for MAS apps. If this sounds more like the direction you want to go, there are different answers.

Comment: @abarnert How do you suggest doing this?

Comment: You have to answer at least some of my questions before I can suggest any answers. Do you want overall summary info, or do you actually want to know about each process? Do you want to find ways to get around the sandbox? For that matter, exactly what (end-user-visible) goal are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I parse the output of top using a shell script. I let the user see full system cpu info and memory usage. Please look here for any more clarification http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quicktoggles/id523523036?mt=12

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "full system cpu info and memory usage". Again, summaries or each process?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to show information about each running process, like Activity Monitor's main window. You just can't do it in the sandbox. Period.*

So, file a radar asking Apple to give you a way to do it, and explaining why you think it's justified. And in the mean time, stay unsandboxed. And if Apple tells you that you're not supposed to be able to do this (which I think is a likely outcome), then you have to either remove that feature, or stop selling in the App Store (and find some way to transition your existing users to another channel).

And really, it looks like half of what your app does isn't going to work in the sandbox—and is already against the MAS guidelines anyway, which means every time you submit an update you risk getting rejected and being stuck.

*Actually, you could do it by, e.g., sending scripts to Activity Monitor and scraping its output through UI scripting or something, if the user has enabled accessibility, but even if that works, the MAS reviewers will not like it… so don't.